# Error converting to IMicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to create new Azure Active Directory application, using this PowerShell command:

```
$SecurePassword=ConvertTo-SecureString {password} -asplaintext -force
New-AzADApplication -DisplayName {Display name} -HomePage {Home page URL} -IdentifierUris {Application identifier} -Password $SecurePassword
```

But I get an error that says `Cannot convert value "System.Security.SecureString" to type "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.IMicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential[]".`

Here's the full error:

```
New-AzADApplication: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'PasswordCredentials'. Cannot convert value "System.Security.SecureString" to type "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.IMicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential[]". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Security.SecureString" value of type "System.Security.SecureString" to type "Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Cmdlets.Resources.MSGraph.Models.ApiV10.IMicrosoftGraphPasswordCredential"."
```

Yet, I can't find any information about how to convert another way. I'm relatively new to PowerShell though. Anyone know how to resolve this error? Thank you.

The command came from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-rm-rest

Comment: I think what you need is to create an [Azure Service Principal with password](https://www.jorgebernhardt.com/azure-service-principal-password/) for the `-PasswordCredentials` parameter instead of a SecureString

Comment: That step comes after the one I'm stuck on, but thanks anyway. I discovered this article is very old, so I think some of the `Az` commands are outdated. And there was a switch in the Azure Active Directory to `MSGraph`, so the `-Password` flag won't work anymore. I'll keep digging though.

Answer (score 0):

The latest **[New-AzADApplication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azps-msgraph-migration-changes?view=azps-8.3.0#new-azadapplication)** cmdlet has not contain the Password parameter. Thats why it is throwing the below error.
[image]

#### Workaround to avoid the issue:

1. First create the Azure AD Application `New-AzADApplication` as a Service principal `New-AzADServicePrincipal`.

```
#creating AZ AD Application
 $myApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "<Application Display Name>" -IdentifierUris '<Application Identifier Url>'
 # AD application Service principal 
 New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $myApp.ApplicationId.Guid -SkipAssignment
```

2. Use the **[New-AzADAppCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.Resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-0.10.0#syntax)** cmdlet to add a custom password,

```
#In this way we can add our password
 $SecurePassword  =  ConvertTo-SecureString  -String  "<Your custom password>"  -AsPlainText  -Force  
 New-AzADAppCredential  -ObjectId  "<AD Application object Id>"  -Password  $SecurePassword
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, that the `-Password` was no longer valid. However, I tried the command you have in #1, but getting this error: `New-AzADServicePrincipal: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'ApplicationId'. Cannot convert null to type "System.Guid".`

Comment: The first part of that command worked though, I tried this: `$myApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "my-ad-app" -IdentifierUris "api://my-app-id"`. I don't have any real domains, so I have to use it as an ID.

Comment: You have to mention the application (app id) which already added with Azure AD. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#identifieruris-attribute) according to your application within the Azure AD.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, mention it where? I tried to put my app name at the end of the URL, but that didn't work. The next command (the service principle one) I run still returns a null error. Based on my example could you give me example commands? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Delliganesh got this to work with a -Password property, as that isn't a member of New-AzADAppCredential. When you do this you are asking the application to create a new key and secret for you, that you must record in order to work with it. If you pipe New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId "xxx...." to Get-Member, you will see that there isn't a -Password property for it. So, in order to get this to work, do the following:

$myApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "Application Display Name"
-IdentifierUris "Application Identifier Url"

New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $myApp.AppId

Then, in the Azure Portal, go to App Registrations and locate your new App. In the Overview for it, you will see the Object ID. Copy that to the clipboard, and then:

New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId "xxx....."

This will generate the key and secret that I mentioned earlier, which you should make a note of. Also note the expiry date and time if you plan to use them long-term.